# Windows clipboard trouble.

Tags: keyboard, java, clipboard

I done research and nothing helped so I've come to ask a question.

About a month ago i was working on my minecraft server. I didn't want to retype something so I just used copy and paste. I copied the following phrase from java based minecraft client.

```
t &bbacking up skywars, will be back up soon
```

Every now and again sometimes when I press CTRL + V that phrase comes up. But usually it goes away.

Now whenever I press CTRL + V that phrase comes up. It is interesting because if I use right click copy and paste, copy and paste works regularly. it is also interesting then when I press CTRL + V and I keep pressing ether C or V while holding CTRL, it will just type ccvccvcvcvcvcvcv without performing paste or copy.

So I have come to deal with the problem by using right click for all my copy and pasting needs.

I have tried using

```
cmd /c "echo off | clip"
```

to attempt to clear my keyboard, however the phrase is still there.

Comment: We have no idea what operating system your using.  Second I would imagine if you did a reboot the problem would go away.  Its also not clear what your question is.

Comment: Sounds like your CTRL key is busted. Have you tried using the other one on your keyboard?

Comment: windows 7. Reboot didn't work earlier today.
How could my CTRL key be busted? When I press CTRL + V it pastes "t &bbacking up skywars, will be back up soon"